# Dynamically color DateDialog

Tags: android, datepicker

Is there a way to dynamically color the DateDialog?

My application does not have a universal theme, each activity could have a different primary color. I would like to match the DateDialog's colors with the colors of the activity it is on.

Comment: You should create a style for each activity and define accent color for each style.

Comment: above solution is correct. @septemberboy right

Comment: Thanks. I wish there was just a simple setter